# Entity Framework inserting row for navigation property even if key is found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework. I have a table Person that has a foreign key on Table PersonCategory. Person Id is an  auto-incremented identity (1,1). Each time i update the person entity the entity framework inserts a row for PersonCategory Table Even if category is found.

I am using Database first design.

```
class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set}
  public PersonCategory {get;set;}
}

class PersonCategory
{
  public int ID {get;set}
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to attach the existing `PersonCategory` to the context;

```
var myPersonCat = new PersonCategory { ID = 1, Name = "Foo" };
var myPerson = new Person { Name = "Bar", PersonCategory = myPersonCat };

context.PersonCategories.Attach(myPersonCat);    
context.People.Add(myPerson);
```

Comment: I am using a Generic Repository pattern. I tried this way it's still inserting a Person Category and updating the Person object to it. Whether on update person or on Add new person

Comment: @Jey You may have done it incorrectly. Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: `using (GenericRepository<User> userAccountRepository = new GenericRepository<User>())
                { 
 using (GenericRepository<Country> countryRep = new GenericRepository<Country>())
                    {
                        mycountry = countryRep.First(country => country.ID == 1);                                  user.UserCountry = mycountry;            
                        countryRep.Attach(mycountry);
                        userAccountRepository.Add(user);
                        userAccountRepository.SaveChanges();          
                    } }`

Comment: @Jey It looks like each of your repositories are using their own `ObjectContext/DbContext` instance. Change your `GenericRepository` implementation to use single context.

Comment: Why do we have to `Attach(myPersonCat)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `State` of your `PersonCategory` to `Unchanged` before you save your `Person`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you're using to update?
Sounds to me that you're adding a new person everytime, and with a person category get added for the new record. 
What you want is retrieve the person you want from the EF context, update the fields you want, and persist the changes to the context, without adding any new element to your db, this way you're only modifying an existing record, existing relationships will be maintained. Something like

```
var myPerson = context.People.FindbyId(personId);
myPerson.Name = "Joe";
myPerson.Age = "20";

context.SaveAllChanges();
```

Comment: it happens in both when i try to insert a new Person or when i try to modify an existing one.